# Dropping an element to another row of elements fails to work when dropped in front of first or after last element

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I am trying to build a very simple drag and drop website. The user can drag a preset 'section' from a sidebar which contains different numbers of columns, referred to as 'cells'. The user drags it onto a canvas and can rearrange the cells and sections. Sections are in rows, and are the parent of these cells.

The issue is that the user is not able to move a cell from one section to another section if they try to drop it **in front of the first cell of that section** or **after the last cell of that section.** Anything in between is working.

Code snippet:

```
             if (userOption.classList.contains('gen-section')) { // Different actions depending on class of element
                let dropPosition = ev.clientY;
                let elements = document.querySelectorAll('.gen-section');
                let closestElement = null;
                elements.forEach((element) => {
                    if (!closestElement || Math.abs(dropPosition - element.getBoundingClientRect().top) < Math.abs(dropPosition - closestElement.getBoundingClientRect().top)) {
                        closestElement = element;
                    }
                });

                if (dropPosition < closestElement.getBoundingClientRect().top + closestElement.offsetHeight / 2) {
                    // Insert before the closest element if the drop position is above its midpoint
                    closestElement.parentNode.insertBefore(userOption, closestElement);
                } else {
                    // Insert after the closest element if the drop position is below its midpoint
                    closestElement.parentNode.insertBefore(userOption, closestElement.nextSibling);
                }
            } else if (userOption.classList.contains('gen-cell')) {
                let dropPositionX = ev.clientX;
                let elements = document.querySelectorAll('.gen-cell');
                let closestElement = null;

                elements.forEach((element) => {
                    if (!closestElement || Math.abs(dropPositionX - element.getBoundingClientRect().left) < Math.abs(dropPositionX - closestElement.getBoundingClientRect().left)) {
                        closestElement = element;
                    }
                });

                let hoveredElement = ev.target;
                let closestCell = hoveredElement.closest(".gen-cell");
                let closestSection = hoveredElement.closest(".gen-section");

                if (closestSection.hasChildNodes()) {
                    if (Math.abs(dropPositionX - closestElement.getBoundingClientRect().left) < Math.abs(dropPositionX - closestElement.getBoundingClientRect().right)) {
                        // Insert before the closest element if the drop position is left of its midpoint
                        closestElement.parentNode.insertBefore(userOption, closestElement);
                    } else {
                        closestElement.parentNode.insertBefore(userOption, closestElement.nextSibling);
                    }
                } else {
                    // Insert into an empty section
                    hoveredElement.appendChild(userOption);
                }
            }
```

Also, when I drag and drop a cell inside of a section that only contains itself, it drops itself into another section below when it should stay where it is. I am not sure where I have gone wrong in my logic, or if I am missing a piece of code which I have completely overlooked.